# Why does composer autoload_static.php have error with php 5.5?

Tags: php, composer-php

Composer gives error with php 5.5. Parse error in composer\autoload_static.php at line 10 - syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ')'

and line 10 of that file is:

```
'34901568a1e26d13dd475cb2c85e0284' => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/zendframework/zend-form/autoload/formElementManagerPolyfill.php',
```

in the file below. It works fine with 5.6, but I don't understand what is its problem with 5.5? It seems a valid php. Please advise.

```
<?php

// autoload_static.php @generated by Composer

namespace Composer\Autoload;

class ComposerStaticInitf5fb4a6513c4bb8e1183f32a6d8a31be
{
public static $files = array (
'34901568a1e26d13dd475cb2c85e0284' => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/zendframework/zend-form/autoload/formElementManagerPolyfill.php',
'0e6d7bf4a5811bfa5cf40c5ccd6fae6a' => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/symfony/polyfill-mbstring/bootstrap.php',
'3e2471375464aac821502deb0ac64275' => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/symfony/polyfill-php54/bootstrap.php',
'6a47392539ca2329373e0d33e1dba053' => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/symfony/polyfill-intl-icu/bootstrap.php',
'67153d798259e2422f77ee379077b565' => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/minfraud/http/src/HTTPBase.php',
'038a1d49667b1c077e3f164315eba901' => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/minfraud/http/src/CreditCardFraudDetection.php',
);
```

Comment: [Constant scalar expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php) are supported in PHP >= 5.6

Comment: So if I use autoload.php on php 5.5, will I get the error? Or it uses its other files like *_files.php, *_classmap.php etc? Or what to do to have autoload.php compatible with 5.5?